# Don't run android application in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

When I want to run my java code, I have this problem :

```
Exeption in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:0
     at com.ibm.icu.text.BreakDictionary.main(BreakDictionary.java:44)
```

i can't run my code... It's simple

```
public class main{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      System.out.print("Hi");
   }
}
```

Comment: what the _real code_? In your sample you neither used args array nor I see `BreakDictionary` being used!

Comment: FYI, class names should be capitalized by convention and it's not really a good idea to call a class Main. Also, tell us how you're running this code (such as a command on the command line).

Comment: I don't have any class with BreakDictionary name... it's my real code... may be it's a source of plug ins...

Comment: I change my class name to MyClass but it's not successfull...
I am using eclipse and add swt...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WTF is `com.ibm.icu.text.BreakDictionary`?

Make sure of the class whose main you are running. I suspect you're not running *your* class. Your java command should look like this:

```
java -cp somepath com.mycompany.mypackage.MyClass
```

Better yet, use an IDE like eclipse that make it easy to run a class

Also, rename your class from `main` to `MyClass` - anything with a leading capital letter - it's good coding style

Comment: maybe, but as lame as it is, I consider it to be the answer

Comment: @AliSh If you're using eclipse, right click on source and > Run as > Java Application

Answer (score 1):

```
Exeption in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:0
 at com.ibm.icu.text.BreakDictionary.main(BreakDictionary.java:44)
```

This exception says that you are running the `main` method in a class named `BreakDictionary`.  In your sample code the class is called `main`.

You can solve this in eclipse by right-clicking your class and select run as and then java application. This will ensure that you are using your main class as the entry point and not BreakDictionary (which seems to either be on your classpath or you are simply not running the correct project in eclipse).